# Create a runtime table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Suppose that I have two tables:

```
tableA (id, name);
tableB (id, name);
```

I also have a textual file with a list of couples of ids:

```
id1a, id2a
id1b, id2b
...
```

I would like to run the following query:

```
select *
from (
id1a, id2a
id1b, id2b
...)
join tableA as a on a.id = id1
join tableB as b on b.id = id2;
```

How can I write such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare a query with a **[`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html)** expression:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM  (
   VALUES 
      (id1a, id2a)
     ,(id1b, id2b)
     , ...
   )   t(id1, id2)
JOIN   tablea a ON a.id = t.id1
JOIN   tableb b ON b.id = t.id2;
```

Or you **[`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)** the values from the text file to a temporary table and proceed from there:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t(id1 int, id2 int);

COPY t FROM '/path/to/file.csv';

SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   t
JOIN   tablea a ON a.id = t.id1
JOIN   tableb b ON b.id = t.id2;
```